# VBA Copying Excel Columns to different Workbooks and Closing the Files

Tags: vba, excel

I have this work-based project to where the VBA will automatically copy select columns to certain worksheets within different workbooks.

```
Sub Macro2()
MsgBox "It's working 2"


Dim incidentDataColumnC As Range, SpecificDataColumnA As Range

Set incidentDataColumnC = Workbooks("01 - January 2017 Incident Data.csv").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")
Set SpecificDataColumnA = Workbooks.Open("Z:\****\Real Test\01 - January 2017 Service Desk Reports.xlsx").Worksheets(3).Columns("A")

incidentDataColumnC.Copy Destination:=SpecificDataColumnA
SpecificDataColumnA.Parent.Close

Dim incidentDataColumnE As Range, SpecificDataColumnB As Range

Set incidentDataColumnE = Workbooks("01 - January 2017 Incident Data.csv").Worksheets(1).Columns("E")
Set SpecificDataColumnB = Workbooks.Open("Z:\****\Real Test\01 - January 2017 Service Desk Reports.xlsx").Worksheets(3).Columns("B")


incidentDataColumnE.Copy Destination:=SpecificDataColumnB
SpecificDataColumnB.Close

Dim incidentDataColumnH As Range, SpecificDataColumnC As Range

Set incidentDataColumnH = Workbooks("01 - January 2017 Incident Data.csv").Worksheets(1).Columns("H")
Set SpecificDataColumnC = Workbooks.Open("Z:\****\Real Test\01 - January 2017 Service Desk Reports.xlsx").Worksheets(3).Columns("C")

incidentDataColumnH.Copy Destination:=SpecificDataColumnC
SpecificDataColumnC.Close
....
....
MsgBox "It ran"
End Sub
```

The code functions the way it is supposed to by copying the columns, but it comes back with an error saying that the destination file is already open.

I want to find a way around this error, and if possible to close each of the files after the copy procedure runs.

I have tried a simple .Close command, but an error pops up saying that it is unsupported.

Comment: The simple answer is open the workbook once, not three times.

Comment: Please declare some object variables and get back to us: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251791.aspx

Comment: `SpecificDataColumnC` is a `Range`, you can't do `SpecificDataColumnC.Close`, ditto for `SpecificDataColumnB`. Also, see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Workbook objects to keep track of your workbooks.  You can also simplify your code a lot by just copying the ranges directly, rather than assigning objects to each individual range.

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    MsgBox "It's working 2"

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("01 - January 2017 Incident Data.csv")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("Z:\****\Real Test\01 - January 2017 Service Desk Reports.xlsx")

    wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("C").Copy wb2.Worksheets(3).Columns("A")
    wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("E").Copy wb2.Worksheets(3).Columns("B")
    wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns("H").Copy wb2.Worksheets(3).Columns("C")
    '....
    '....
    wb2.Close
    MsgBox "It ran"
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked, but it does display a prompt to save changes, is there a way to have it save the changes, thus causing the prompt to not display?

Comment: @DylanF - Yes, the `Close` method has a parameter to specify whether to save changes.  So you could say, for example, `wb2.Close SaveChanges:=True`.  (I didn't include that because you didn't include it in the code in your question, so I assumed you wanted the user to choose whether to save the changes or not.)

Comment: Actually it did not copy at all, is there a step I am missing from your solution?

Comment: @DylanF It works fine for me (although I just used dummy workbooks obviously).

Comment: Hmmm, odd, since I deleted all info on the destination page and saved it in order to detect any changes. 
The program runs, but the end result is the page still blank.

Comment: @DylanF Place a breakpoint on the `Close` line and then, when it breaks, have a look at the workbook (which would be open at that time) and see whether it is changed - that will tell me whether the copies aren't working or whether the save isn't working.  (Or, step through the code and see what the workbook looks like after each copy.)

Comment: I placed the breakpoint on the close line and all, but nothing quite happened. The destination worksheet, which is the "Service Desk Reports", is still blank, somehow the copying procedure did not work.

Comment: @DylanF - This might be a stupid question but are you sure you are looking at the right worksheet in the "xlsx" file?  (The third worksheet from the left-most one when looking at the worksheet tabs.)  And you don't have any hidden sheets that might be confusing the numbering?  Place a `MsgBox wb2.Worksheets(3).Name` prior to the `Close` and see whether it is giving the right sheet name.

Comment: I think you nailed it on the head, for some reason it was selecting the second worksheet from the left oddly enough, so I incremented the number and it selected the correct sheet. Which is apparently is sheet number 4, even though it is the third sheet from the left. 
Thank you for identifying that problem and all!